# How do I load an image/byte array in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to have a page load an image from the database using @Url.Page. I can see it hits the PageModel handler method, but the image is never visible.

Everything I've found relates to Razor views with MVC. I'm specifically working with Razor Pages and do not have controllers, just Page Models.

Page:

```
            <div class="row" style="@(Model.ImageFileId.HasValue ? "" : "display: none;")">
               <div class="form-group col-1">
                  <label>Existing Image: </label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-11">
                  <img src="@Url.Page("Edit", "FilePreview", new { imageFileId = Model.ImageFileId })" />
               </div>
            </div>
```

Page Handler method:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetFilePreview(int imageFileId)
        {
            // Get Image File from database
            File imageFile = await _fileService.GetFileById(imageFileId);

            return File(imageFile.FileContent, imageFile.MimeType, imageFile.FileName);
        }
```

Comment: You should start by viewing the page source to see if the correct src value is generated.

Comment: @Mike Brind I've checked the src value and I think it's what I would expect. It's `<img src="/admin/stories/edit/filepreview?imageFileId=49676">`

Comment: What does the request to that URL return?

Comment: Have you checked that if `Model.ImageFileId`  has really a value which is byte[] image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the code I had written was fine, and that the data I was saving in the database and thus returning was not a byte array, and instead a Base64 string.If someone stumbles on this question, the method I've used to display an image from the db saved as a byte[] ashould work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I test with my project,it can work,you need to make sure the file you returned is correct.Here is a demo:

View:

```
<img src="@Url.Page("Index5", "FilePreview", new { imageFileId = 1 })" />
```

handler(I test with a file in wwwroot):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetFilePreview(int imageFileId)
        {
         
            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\imgs\1.jpg");

            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "1.jpg");
            
        }
```

result:
[image]